# Issue with sfDoctrine plugin in symfony 1.4 version

Tags: symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I got my project code from server and configured it in localhost. It's running okay but facing issues with sfDoctrine plugin.

Recently i started working on symfony. My project was built on symfony framework. I have downloaded all the code from server(Live site) and installed it in my localhost. And created one virtual host and done configurations with database and all. The front end is working fine but backend is not working fine.

Issues were: admin.css, default.css, images required for back-end template are not loading, That's why back-end was broken. I have checked with it. I came to know that the stylesheets are loading from sfDoctrine plugin. When i click on view-source and opened it then it have given page not found error.

sfDoctrine plugin needs any other configurations?

I am sure that it was because of sfDoctrine.

Comment: Try to run `php symfony plugin:publish-assets`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried it but it's giving warning with syslink() function.